# Bevel selected edge

Tags: python

Hello I'm following some tutorial on Blender 2.5. Author shows how to use Bevel on cube's edge. Here is simple code (edit mode is on):

```
cube = bpy.context.active_object
cube.data.edges[0].bevel_weight = 1.0
```

But when i try this code in Blender 2.69/2.71, I can't see any changes. When I do it by shortcut ctrl+b it works